# Cannot Add Value to Variable in Sql While Loop

Tags: t-sql

In the following while loop, the variable `@total` is resulted as `NULL` when adding selected value from table. If not adding, the result is shown as selected value from table but only the last row's value.

```
SET @coundDate = '1/1/2012';

WHILE ( Datepart(dd, @countDate) < Datepart(dd, @endDate) )
  BEGIN
      SET @total = @total + (SELECT Cast([7am] AS INT) + 
                                    Cast([8am]AS INT) AS TotalHitCount
                             FROM   Sale
                             WHERE  TransactionDate = @countDate);
      SET @countDate = Dateadd(d, 1, @countDate);
  END;

SELECT @total
```

I'm now confusing a lot. What's that error?

Comment: Why are you doing this in a loop. Won't `SUM` work for you?

Comment: How to 'group by' in this condition?

Comment: From the code you have shown you wouldn't need a `group by`. Just a `where` to select only the rows of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin points out, you could write your entire query as a simple `SUM`:

```
SELECT SUM(Cast([7am] AS INT) + Cast([8am]AS INT)) AS Total
FROM   Sale
WHERE  TransactionDate between '20120101' and @endDate
```

Although I would query why `7am` and `8am` aren't already `int`s.

Comment: Probably safer to do `SUM(ISNULL(Cast([7am] AS INT),0) + ISNULL(Cast([8am] AS INT),0)) AS Total`. One of the reasons they might have got their original behaviour would be if one of the values is `NULL` and this will lose the non null value.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pre-init your variable with default value like 0 :)

Comment: @NayLinAung - you're not initializing `@total` in the code you've shown (although the code you've shown obviously isn't your real code)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - If you can't help, please don't make useless assumptions. It is the real code in my Business Activity Monitoring System of BIT project. How can I show every pieces of the code? I only posted the part of code where error occurred.

Comment: Useless assumptions? Your first line assigns to a variable called `@coundDate`, not `@countDate`. Therefore, this *isn't* the real code. All we can work with is what you *do* post.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - that's my only typing error. Sorry for that. And I think it is not too much related with the error. If my comment insulted u, I'm really sorry for that. I swear that's my real code and I am here to find out the answer, not to argue about non-related factors.